# What is difference between built-in "void" and "VOID" from "typedef void VOID"?

Tags: c++, typedef, void

Accidentally I have the following issue:

```
typedef void VOID;

class Cls1
｛
public:
  VOID Clear(VOID);
};
```

And the compiler (g++ 4.6.1) reported

> error: 'anonymous' has incomplete type
>   error: 'invalid use of 'VOID {aka void}'

Is there a particular reason 'void' differ from 'VOID'?

Comment: The [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.4) has a good write up on the use of `f(void);`.

Comment: declaring a void parameter list with a typedef is nonstandard

Comment: This question I see many times. Try google before ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the clang compiler gives a more readable error:

> test.cpp:14:20: error: empty parameter list defined with a typedef of
>   'void' not allowed in C++
>       void Clear(VOID);

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing different.

In C++ empty parameter lists are empty, not "void".

Comment: I prefer to explicitly add "void" for empty parameter lists, as in C empty parameter lists without "void" assumes you can pass arbitrary params.

Comment: @xis19: you need to decide if you're writing C or C++ code though. In C++, an empty parameter list is idiomatic

Comment: @xis19 - OK. vOv  I like to name all my C++ variables with '$' at the beginning because that's how it's done in Perl.

Comment: @xis19, C doesn't have member functions, following C rules for member functions makes no sense. In C++ `f(void)` is considered an abomination, but tolerated for C compatibility. Doing the same with a typedef is so abominable it's not even allowed.